# Como aplicar a lógica que eu usei no procedure dentro da function?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Eu quero Criar uma função que some todos os clientes cadastrados em uma loja durante um dia.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `func`() RETURNS char(100) CHARSET utf8mb4
 BEGIN
 RETURN (SELECT count(*), data FROM users group by data order by data);
 END
```

Mas quando eu tento executar usando o comando:

```
SELECT func();
```

Eu tenho o seguinte erro:

*20:16:29   select func() LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)    0.000 sec*

Tenho uma tabela chamada users, que contém os campos id, nome, profissao e data. tentei várias variações disso porém não consegui.

Consegui o resultado desejado mas usando procedure, dessa forma:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `relat`()
 BEGIN
 SELECT count(*),data FROM users group by data order by data asc;
 END

call relat();
```

porém quero aprender com function também.

Comment: Funções no mysql [não podem retornar tabelas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-loadable.html).

Comment: @bfavaretto então  a solução só seria possível em procedure mesmo?

Comment: Sim. Use funções quando precisar retornar valores escalares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução do problema ficou assim:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `func`(thisdate date) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
 RETURN (SELECT count(*) FROM users where thisdate = data);
END
```

```
select func('2008-11-05') as Registros;
```

*No caso será passado como parâmetro a data que deseja ver a quantidade de registros.*

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
create function func()
returns int deterministic
begin           
    return(
SELECT
    count(*),
    data
FROM
    users
group by
    data
order by
    data);
end;
```

Comment: Dessa Forma não deu o resultado que eu queria, porém me ajudou a pensar na solução, obrigado.